# DocuSign Node.js SDK: Error: RECIPIENTS_NOT_PROVIDED

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the Node.js DoucSign SDK to send out docs for signatures. Currently, we are getting the RECIPIENTS_NOT_PROVIDED error when we try to send it via our CRM. Our CRM calls our API when a a status is changed which should send the docs. In our Graphql API Playground we are able to successfully create and send the envelope with no issue. I am sure I am missing something but I just can't see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
let signer1 = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
      email: args.signorEmail,
      name: `${args.signorLegalName}`,
      tabs: signerTabs,
      roleName: 'signer',
      recipientId: '1'
    });
    
    let cc1 = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
      email: !!args.ccEmail,
      name: !!args.ccName,
      tabs: ccTabs,
      roleName: 'signer',
      recipientId: '2'
    });

    // Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
    env.templateRoles = [signer1, cc1];
    env.status = 'sent';
```

Here is our successful template roles via our playground:

```
"[{"email":"signorEmail",
"name":"Jane Doe",
"roleName":"signer",
"tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"anchorString":"{{Signature_1}}"}],
"textTabs":[Removed Tabs]}},
{"email": "ccEmail",
"name":"John Smith",
"roleName":"cc",
"tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"anchorString":"{{Signature_2}}"}],"textTabs":[removed Tabs]
}}]"
```

Unsuccessful:

```
"[{"email": "signorEmail",
"name":"Test 1",
"roleName":"signer",
"tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"anchorString":"{{Signature_1}}"}],
"textTabs":[Removed Tabs]}},
{"email": "ccEmail",
"name":"John Smith",
"roleName":"cc",
"tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"anchorString":"{{Signature_2}}"}],"textTabs":[removed Tabs]
}}]"
```

Comment: Edited to clean up the unsuccessful JSON

Answer (score 0):

Well,
First, I see two recipients with the same **roleName** ('signer') which suggest to me one of them is wrong. RoleNames should be unique inside the same template.
In terms of why the first JSON is ok and the second is not, they seem to be the same except that the second is not valid JSON at all. Just use any JSON validator and check out some missing brackets etc.

Comment: Thanks Inbar! I will try to change the roleName and see if that works. Just curious why it would work in one instance and not the other? Also, the JSON is off because I was trying to clean it up, format it, and make it easier to read so I apologize for my kistake with that.

Comment: Updated to change the second template role from "signer" to "cc". I am still receiving the same error where it states: Recipients Not Found @Inbar Gazit

Comment: well, what are the names of the roles in your template? you have to match all of them so that you have a complete envelope

Comment: Hi @Inbar. I had a role of 'signer' which would successfully send out the envelopes via our playground. I went into Templates, selected the doc in question, updated it to have another role of 'cc', and it was successfully sent via our playground but not our CRM. Unfortunately, we are still in the same spot. Is there anything I can provide that would be beneficial?

Comment: not sure what you mean by playground vs. CRM. 
I would need a lot more information on how your CRM works. Are you talking Salesforce? do you use the Apex toolkit? how do you configure it? auth?

Comment: So we have an environment/playground where we are able to call different functionality from our API. In this case, we are integrating with DocuSign SDK to create and send envelopes and we use the JWT authorization method. We use Dynamics 365 but we have functionality that will call our sendEnvelope functionality from within our API so everything is coming from our API

Comment: so, you have a component, that components works just fine, but when you hook that component to Dynamics 365 it breaks? I'm not sure I can help with this, I would have to understand a lot more about your Dynamics 365 code and what it does. You can also use  a sniffer to see what is actually sent to the API, because it is probably different. The API would behave 100% the same if the same call was made.

Comment: Our CRM makes the same call as our playground does and the request should be the same between our playground and dynamics but for whatever reason it fails when called from dynamics. I will check out a sniffer and I appreciate your help.